# Regular expression on ? operation_python

Tags: python, regex

I would like to ask why the first expression doesn't output ('a', 'b','c','d') from the string 'axxxxxbcd'.

```
import re
match = re.findall(r'(a).*?(b)?.*?(c)?(d)','awsssd axxxxxbcd ad adfdfdcdfdd 
awsbdfdfdcd')
print (match)
```

output[1]: [('a', '', '', 'd'), ('a', '', 'c', 'd'), ('a', '', '', 'd'), ('a', '', '', 'd'), ('a', '', '', 'd')]

```
import re

match = re.findall(r'(a).*?(b)?(c)?(d)','awsssd axxxxxbcd ad adfdfdcdfdd awsbdfdfdcd')
print (match)
```

output[2]: [('a', '', '', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', '', '', 'd'), ('a', '', '', 'd'), ('a', 'b', '', 'd')]

Comment: it might be because `?` is... lazy i think? so it might prefer 0 matches to 1 match...

Comment: @coldspeed I dont think this is a duplicate. This is more specific to regex and why `(b)?` is matching nothing rather than something (eg: why the `.*?` before it consumes the `b`)

Comment: This is also an interesting example (in JavaScript): `"xbx".match(/.*?(b)?.*?/)` which, now that I look closely, all the `?` allow the regex to match *nothing* (any 0 characters + 0 b's + any 0 characters = empty match)

Comment: this question keeps getting interesting http://i.imgur.com/gdVIO1i.png

Comment: @COLDSPPED Can you undo the mark? I didn't find the answer.

Comment: On closer inspection it seems your question is more of a "help me debug" type of question.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert at regex engines, but looks like internally the regex engine eats characters to feed the second `.*?` before the first, skipping the `(b)?` part as it is optional.
Not sure if it's clear enough, but I guess you'll got it on [regex101 debugger](https://regex101.com/r/Jqxt8k/1/debugger).

That said, adding a little [contrast](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast) instead of picking any character could save your match:

```
(a)[^bcd\s]*(b)?[^cd\s]*(c)?(d)
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/EB1G9g/1).